# 0x API: Am I able to Swap absolutely NEW coins?

Tags: ether, bsc, 0x, decentralized-exchange, trading

I have a trading bot that operates on newly created tokens in BSC and ETH networks. It works only for new tokens, that were created with WBNB (BSC chain with PancakeSwap) or with WETH (ETH chain with UniSwap) in pair.

My question is simple: Am I able to delegate Swapping mechanism for **NEWLY** created tokens to 0x API?
Or maybe there is some other third-party app, that can handle Swaps in this way?